# Python : divide array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Lets say i have array like this :

```
 d= [[1.254,3.458,9.874][5.32,3.35,4.54][1.121,8.121,9.45][7.1215,9.454,8.14].... and etc.]
```

How i can divide d[0] [2] element with d[0] [2], d[1] [2],d[2] [2], d[3] [2] ....... and etc?
I will explain it by using numbers:

```
  9.874(d[0] [2])/9.874(d[0] [2])
  9.874(d[0] [2])/4.45(d[1] [2]) 
  9.874(d[0] [2])/9.45(d[2] [2])
  9.874(d[0] [2])/8.14(d[3] [2]) ........ and etc.
```

And i want that my result would be in array :

```
  Result  = [1,2.21,1.04,1.21,... and etc.]
```

Or (if its easier) result can be added to current array :

```
  d= [[1.254,3.458,9.874,1][5.32,3.35,4.54,2.21][1.121,8.121,9.45,1.04][7.1215,9.454,8.14,1.21].... and etc.]
```

As you can see result is the last array of array element:

```
  d[0] [3] = 1, d[1] [3] = 2.21, d[2] [3]=1.04, d[3] [3]=1.21
```

If anyone need more explanation please write in a comment section dont add -1 :(

Comment: Well, it's a pretty unclear question.

Comment: what section is unclear i can fix it

Comment: Are you trying to do matrix arithmetic?   Some of the aspects that are unclear: division is not defined for arrays, `0 2` is a syntax error, not a valid array index, and numbers are not functions that can be called.

Comment: Please be aware that you don't have an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your example:

```
result = [d[0][2]/dx[2] for dx in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last element of each inner list you could do

```
d= [[1.254,3.458,9.874,1],[5.32,3.35,4.54,2.21],[1.121,8.121,9.45,1.04],[7.1215,9.454,8.14,1.21]]

for i in d: print i[-1]

1
2.21
1.04
1.21
```

and if you want it as a list you can use list comprehension

```
l = [i[-1] for i in d]
print l

[1, 2.21, 1.04, 1.21]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Numpy, you can add a column to your array and fill it with the results of your division:

```
1: a = np.array([[1.254,3.458,9.874],[5.32,3.35,4.54][1.121,8.121,9.45],[7.1215,9.454,8.14]])
2: b =np.hstack((a, np.zeros((a.shape[0],1))))
3: b[:,3] = b[0,2]/b[:,2]
4: b
array([[ 1.254     ,  3.458     ,  9.874     ,  1.        ],
   [ 5.32      ,  3.35      ,  4.54      ,  2.17488987],
   [ 1.121     ,  8.121     ,  9.45      ,  1.04486772],
   [ 7.1215    ,  9.454     ,  8.14      ,  1.21302211]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler would be to compute a list comprehension (solution proposed by @elzell) `result = [d[0][2]/dx[2] for dx in d]`

You can also add the resul as last element of each sublist (array in numpy is a different animal)

```
for dx in d:
    dx.append(d[0][2]/dx[2])
```

Comment: Srr added answered for @elzell :) it was his idea first :)

Comment: @user5568235: I was about to suggest it to you. That's the reason why I had explicitely given him credit for his answer. Mine was to show the possibility of changing the array. I had already upvoted his answer :-)